# Closed form for $(n^2+1^2)(n^2+2^2)...(n^2+(n-1)^2)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, factorial, gamma-function, products

> I need closed form for the product $$P_n=(n^2+1^2)(n^2+2^2)...(n^2+(n-1)^2)$$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$

I tried using the properties of Gamma function as follows:
$$P_n= (n+i)(n-i)(n+2i)(n-2i)...(n+(n-1)i)(n-(n-1)i)$$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.
Rearrangement of the above product gives
$$P_n= \left((n+i)(n+2i)...(n+(n-1)i)\right)\left((n-i)(n-2i)...(n-(n-1)i)\right)$$
$$P_n= \left(i^{n-1}\left(\frac{n}{i}+1\right)\left(\frac{n}{i}+2\right)...\left(\frac{n}{i}+(n-1)\right)\right)\left(i^{n-1}\left(\frac{n}{i}-1\right)\left(\frac{n}{i}-2\right)...\left(\frac{n}{i}-(n-1)\right)\right)$$
$$P_n= \left(i^{2n-2}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\frac{n}{i}\left(\frac{n}{i}+1\right)\left(\frac{n}{i}+2\right)...\left(\frac{n}{i}+(n-1)\right)\right)\left(\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\frac{n}{i}\left(\frac{n}{i}-1\right)\left(\frac{n}{i}-2\right)...\left(\frac{n}{i}-(n-1)\right)\right)$$
So we get $$P_n=\frac{i^{2n}}{n^2} \left(\frac{n}{i}\left(\frac{n}{i}+1\right)\left(\frac{n}{i}+2\right)...\left(\frac{n}{i}+(n-1)\right)\right)\left(\frac{n}{i}\left(\frac{n}{i}-1\right)\left(\frac{n}{i}-2\right)...\left(\frac{n}{i}-(n-1)\right)\right)  $$
We can write [using Gamma representation of Falling and rising factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)
$$P_n=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{i}+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{i}\right)}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{i}+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{i}-n+1\right)}  $$
Now we use $\Gamma(z)=(1-z)\Gamma(1-z)$ to get
$$P_n=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{i}+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{i}-n+1\right)}\left(\frac{n}{i}\right)  $$
$$P_n=\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1} i}{n}\right) \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{i}+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{i}-n+1\right)}$$
For $n=1$ the RHS of above formula is $$i \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{i}+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{i}\right)}=i.\frac{1}{i}=1=P_1$$
For $n=2$ the RHS of the above formula is $$-\frac{i}{2}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{2}{i}+2)}{\Gamma(\frac{2}{i}-1)}=-\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{2}{i}+1\right)\left(\frac{2}{i}\right)\left(\frac{2}{i}-1\right) =5=P_2$$
Any help in getting a closed form for the product will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Where does this product come from?

Comment: @Тyma Gaidash I was just thinking about this product. Nothing specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product is equal to $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(k^{2}+n^{2}\right)$.

Using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Product%5BPower%5Bn%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Bk%2C2%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn-1%7D%5D), you can see that, using the Pochhammer Symbol, it can be written as $(1-in)_{n-1}(1+in)_{n-1}$ which can also be written with the gamma function as
$\frac{\sinh(\pi n)\Gamma(n-in)\Gamma(n+in)}{\pi n}$.

Comment: ($+1$) Thanks a lot. But I need the derivation as well. Please include the steps in your answer. I will with utmost respect accept your answer

Comment: @Max Thank you but unfortunately I do not know the derivation because I used Wolfram Alpha. You might be able to find how it was derived by working backwards from the solution.